# New to XSLT/XPATH and Im trying to get past a barrier

Tags: xslt, xpath

This should be simple and everything I read says that select = "name" should select all the nodes with the "name" in an xml document..
So Im trying to work a simple example.. here's the XML: (its a simple inventory app).

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<inventory type="inventory">
<item type="zone" CanAdd="true">
    <title>Building</title>
    <item type="porch" CanAdd="true">
        <title>Porch</title>
    </item>
    <item type="receptionRoom" CanAdd="true">
        <title>Reception Room</title>
        <item type="doorInfo" CanAdd="true">
            <title>Door</title>
            <item type="doorStyleType" select="multi">
                <title>Door Style</title>
                <item>
                    <title>Internal</title>
                </item>
                <item>
                    <title>Plain</title>
                </item>
            </item>
            <item type="doorWinMaterialType" select="single">
                <title>Door Material</title>
                <item type="softwoodColours" select="single">
                    <title>Softwood - Stained</title>
                    <item>
                        <title>Stained Pine</title>
                    </item>
                </item>
            </item>
            <item type="doorwinFurnitureType" select="multi">
                <title>Door Furniture</title>
                <item>
                    <title>Door Handle</title>
                </item>
                <item>
                    <title>LetterBox Opening</title>
                </item>
            </item>
        </item>
    </item>
</item>
<propertyName><![CDATA[2 Street, Village]]></propertyName>
<propertyRef><![CDATA[15p9]]></propertyRef>
</inventory>
```

.. and I need to start to process it with XSLT. (In a C# code behind page - that bit works and throws the result into a pop up.)

The XSLT I am playing with is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" exclude-result-prefixes="msxsl"
xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
            >
<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:template match="/">
    <div>
            <h2>My Inventory</h2>
            <table border="1">
                <tr>
                    <td>
                    <xsl:value-of select="inventory/propertyName" />
                    </td>
                </tr>
            <xsl:for-each select ="item">
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <xsl:value-of select="."/>
                    </td>  
                </tr>
            </xsl:for-each>
            </table>
        <p>Hello world</p>
   </div>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylsheet>
```

The "item" node is not found in the for-each loop and I think I've hit a mental block as to why. I'm sure the answer is glaringly simple when you know it, but at the moment I don't and need to solve this before I can move on so to speak.
The output is: (in a browser)..

```
My Inventory
2 Street, Village 
(I expect a list of the "item" node values here in table rows..)
Hello world
```

Many Thanks,
Brett

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The XPath `item` that you've specified for your `<xsl:for-each>` loop is evaluated relative to the current node, i.e. relative to the document root. In order to select any `<item>` elements at any nesting depth in the document, you will have to use

```
//item
```

However, I think you want something slightly different, as the text of `<item>` elements themselves is their `<title>` text as well as the text of any nested `<item>` elements. Possibly, you are looking for:

```
//item/title
```

To respond directly to your sentence

> everything I read says that select = "name" should select all the nodes with the "name" in an xml document

This is not correct. `select="name"` selects all the elements named "name" in the list of child nodes of the current node, not anywhere in the Xml document.

Comment: Brilliant and thank you .. yes, I realise I need to get further into the the tree and the "Title" elements. I was hitting a block with this though and your help is truly appreciated.

Comment: .. and if you know any good 'getting started' guide links that would be appreciated too. I have done the w3schools intros but they are quite spread out between the differing technologies. Thanks again

Comment: @user1584725, Avoid w3schools -- see why here: http://www.w3fools.com . For links to *good* resources, see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/339930/any-good-xslt-tutorial-book-blog-site-online/341589#341589

Comment: @user1584725: I've often used the W3Schools tutorials because they're pretty well-structured, but what Dimitre pointed out of course points to rather using other tutorials. Nonetheless, the W3Schools element references for XSLT etc. are very handy compared to other references that I've found. Other than that, once you have understood the basic concepts of the language and are looking for details on how to use particular functions or the like, the XPath and XSLT specs are extremely helpful and surprisingly comprehensible.